# Formatting orb tags in MVEL

Tags: java, templates, el, mvel

How to remove the whitespace line generated by @code{}, @if{}, @foreach{}, @end{} etc or Tags in the result of MVEL 2.0 templating?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want whitespace before and after the tags, then don't CR before and after:

for example: Items: @foreach{item : stuff}@{item}@{','}

If you break it onto multiple lines, the whitespace is preserved.